# Install multiple counters (local and general) GA on the site

Tags: google-analytics, counter

The problem is the following, there are 6 sites, each of which has a separate Google Analytics counter, we need to add to each site one more common counter that will show general statistics for all 6 sites. The question is how to do it correctly

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do that depending on what implementation you're using.

- here is a link to how to do that with gtag.js:
  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages#multiple_properties
- here is a link to how to do that with analytics.js (this may also
  require an update of existing tracking):
  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers
- in case if you're using GTM you'll just need to duplicate all the
  analytics tags with a specific tracking ID or use this hack:
  https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/send-google-analytics-tag-multiple-properties/